# Problem with getting data from tables in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have created method in the Yii2 model Users to get all the replies for the current user

`public function getAllRepliesForUsers() { return $this->hasMany(Replies::class, ['user_id' => 'id'])->viaTable('replies_links', ['replies_id' => 'id'])->where(['entity'=>'user']); }`
My replies table[image]
My users table [image]
and the final table that links these two tables [image]

Is my method is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relationship of Users to the Replies. You can use the Model generator of Gii module so you won't get confused by manually typing them.

```
  public function getReplies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Replies::className(), ['id' => 'reply_id'])->viaTable('rply_links', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

(May I know what do you intend to do with the condition ->where(['entity'=>'user'])?).

Comment: because my table structure has 1 table replies that sends replies to the 2 pages (single-user.php, and single-task.php), and because of that i added entity column and marked task/user where reply must be outputted